# How to Insert new Key in APP settings section with web.config Transformation

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, web-config, web.config-transform, xdt-transform

I would like to insert new key value in app settings section and other key values should remains same.

Below is my source config
    <

```
add key="UserName" value="Apple" /> 
    <add key="Main.ConnectionString" value="Data Source=testingdevmachine;Persist Security Info=false;User ID=test;Password=test;Validate Connection=true;" />
        <add key="CTCredentials01" value="userid@test|password@test&12|server@https://test/" />
        <add key="WFCredentials01" value="userid@test|password@Mango| server@https://test/ />
```

`

My Transform config file is looks like:

```
         <add key="CTCredentials01" value="userid@test123|password@test&12|server@https://test/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="WFCredentials01" value="userid@test123|password@Mango| server@https://test/" 
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/> 
    <add key="WFCredentials03" value="userid@test123|password@Mango| server@https://test/" 
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/> 
<add key="UserName" value="Nick"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

> Now, from above transform config add key="WFCredentials03" this key does not have in my source config file so how can I add here in my transform config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you follow [this post](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-transformations-the-definitive-syntax-guide/) but from what I see above

```
<add key="WFCredentials03" value="userid@test123|password@Mango| server@https://test/" 
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

you should change `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"` to `xdt:Transform="Insert"`

Comment: thank you, now I'm able to get it in the target config file by using the above Insert key.